# How to extract data from Facebook pages using FQL in Java

Tags: java, facebook

I want to extract data such as name of page, likes,talking_about_count and page information from any page using FQL in Java. I have written code like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String STR_FACEBOOK_FQL_URL = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=";
    String STR_FACEBOOK_RETURN_FORMAT = "&format=json";
    String STR_FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN = "&access_token=";
    String FQL_GET_QUERY= "SELECT name,likes,about FROM page WHERE id={page-id}"; 
    String encodedQuery;

       try
          {
             encodedQuery = URLEncoder.encode(FQL_GET_QUERY, "UTF-8");
             String faceBookURL = STR_FACEBOOK_FQL_URL + encodedQuery +   
                                      STR_FACEBOOK_RETURN_FORMAT
                      + STR_FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN ;

                    URL url = new URL(faceBookURL);
            InputStream is = url.openStream();

            JSONTokener tok = new JSONTokener(is);
                JSONObject result = new JSONObject(tok);
                System.out.println(result.toString());
                is.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

But this is shownig error like:

```
{"request_args":[{"value":"fql.query","key":"method"},{"value":"SELECT likes,name,about FROM page WHERE uid=me()","key":"query"},{"value":"json","key":"format"},{"value":"id|secret","key":"access_token"}],"error_code":602,"error_msg":"likes is not a member of the page table."}
```

Can anybody tell me, what is the wrong in this code?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please don't use the deprecated endpoint:

```
String STR_FACEBOOK_FQL_URL = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=";
```

is the way to go now. You're using non-existing fields for the `page` table (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/). `likes` needs to be replaced by `fan_count`:

```
String FQL_GET_QUERY= "SELECT name,fan_count,about FROM page WHERE id={page-id}";
```